# Where can I find a list of PEAR DB error codes?

Tags: php, mysql, database, pear

I'm trying to establish a connection to a mysql database using PEAR DB. It's throwing the following error at me:

> DB_Error Object (
>   [error_message_prefix] => [mode] => 1
>   [level] => 1024 [code] => -4 
>   [message] => DB Error: not found
>   [userinfo] => Unable to include the 
>   DB/dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern.php
>   file for
>   'dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern'
>   [backtrace] => Array ( [0] => Array (
>   [file] =>
>   /usr/local/php-5.2.14-2/share/pear/DB.php
>   [line] => 966 [function] => PEAR_Error
>   [class] => PEAR_Error [type] => ->
>   [args] => Array ( [0] => DB Error: not
>   found [1] => -4 [2] => 1 [3] => 1024
>   [4] => Unable to include the
>   DB/dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern.php
>   file for
>   'dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern'
>   ) ) [1] => Array ( [file] =>
>   /usr/local/php-5.2.14-2/share/pear/PEAR.php
>   [line] => 531 [function] => DB_Error
>   [class] => DB_Error [object] =>
>   DB_Error Object *RECURSION* [type] =>
>   -> [args] => Array ( [0] => -4 [1] => 1 [2] => 1024 [3] => Unable to include
>   the
>   DB/dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern.php
>   file for
>   'dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern'
>   ) ) [2] => Array ( [file] =>
>   /usr/local/php-5.2.14-2/share/pear/DB.php
>   [line] => 543 [function] => raiseError
>   [class] => PEAR [object] => DB Object
>   ( ) [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0]
>   => [1] => -4 [2] => [3] => [4] => Unable to include the
>   DB/dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern.php
>   file for
>   'dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern'
>   [5] => DB_Error [6] => 1 ) ) [3] =>
>   Array ( [file] =>
>   /nfs/c07/h04/mnt/xxxxx/domains/wedding.juicywatermelon.com/html/validate.php
>   [line] => 9 [function] => connect
>   [class] => DB [object] => DB Object (
>   ) [type] => -> [args] => Array ( [0]
>   => dbxxxxx:xxxxx@internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com/dbxxxxx_toomodern
>   ) ) ) [callback] => ) 1

my code is as follows:

```
<?php
  require_once('DB.php');
  $db = new DB;
  $db_host = 'internal-db.sxxxxx.gridserver.com'; 
  $db_user = 'xxxxx'; 
  $db_pass = 'xxxxx'; 
  $db_name = 'xxxxx'; 
  $dsn = "$db_user:$db_pass@$db_host/$db_name"; 
  $resource = $db->connect($dsn);
}
```

Can anyone see my error here?
Is there an index of PEAR errors online, I can't for the life of me find them!

Comment: The error codes are documented in the main DB.php, as per http://pear.php.net/manual/en/package.database.db.db-error.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to inlcude the DB type, so if it's MySQL, you would need to change it to

```
$dsn = "mysql://$db_user:$db_pass@$db_host/$db_name";
```